# how can we see output without rectangular boxes

Tags: java, unicode

i have created a table in data base which consists of telugu data .when i am trying to retrieve telugu data by  using eclipse in  java i am getting out with rectangular boxes .

code :

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sloka?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8", "root", "");
        st = con.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("error:" + e);
    }

public void getData() {
    try {
        String query = "select * from eesavyasa ";
        rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.print("records from database");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String name1 = new String(rs.getBytes("firstcolumn"), "UTF-8");
            String name2 = new String(rs.getBytes("secondcolumn"), "UTF-8");
            String name3 = new String(rs.getBytes("thirdcolumn"), "UTF-8");
            String name4 = new String(rs.getBytes("fourthcolumn"), "UTF-8");

            System.out.println(name1);
            System.out.println(name2);
            System.out.println(name3);
            System.out.println(name4);

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.print(ex);
    }

}
```

we have used collation utf-8 for db ,table,for all but we are getting output in rectangular boxes
kindly respond as soon as possible

Comment: You font doesn't support the unicode points...

Comment: can u plz define it precisely

Comment: The characters you want to display are not available in the font you are using, change fonts...

Answer (score 0):

It would be fixed after executing below sql after connected to mysql

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Comment: can u plz define it precisely